# How can I have NetworkManger automatically connect to a network?

Tags: centos7, rhel7, networkmanager

I am trying to prepare several machines that will be used at a single location. I know the SSID of the network and it will be unsecured. Is there a way to add the network in NetworkManager so that once the user logs in, NetworkManager automatically connects to that WiFi network?

The machines will be running CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I added a new entry inside of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` name `ifcfg-Auto-Name_Of_Network` and copied settings from another network. Hopefully this will help someone else! :)